# How import custom indicators blocked source into strategy custom in pineeditor --- tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4, pine-editor

I am trying to add to my custom strategy closed source indicators, but I can't find how to do it, for example, I would like to use the SVP of Market Profile inside my strategy but I can't find how, could you illustrate me how to do it?

Code with execution example